# Max size of PHP array and glob

Tags: php, filesystems, command-line-interface, glob

Hi I'm trying to build a simple CLI script to read all the files in a directory and rename them after applying some simple rules. I am having an issue though in that NOT ALL the items in the directory are being grabbed. I'm assuming that this is do to some limit in PHP or my file system or combination of the two. My question is: Is there a way to increase the memory size or array size limit in PHP so that I can grab all the items at once?

Here is my script.

```
set_time_limit(0);

# \\work\temp\medium
define("BASE", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."work".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."temp".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."medium".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    $files = glob(BASE . "*-1.jpg");

    # echo print_r($files,true);
    # die();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($files as $k => $v) {
        $v = str_replace(BASE, "", $v);
        # echo $v;
        $count++."\r\n";
        echo $count;
    }      
die();
```

I know there are 120,000 items in this folder but my count only gets up to 20,006.  A curious number so I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this for me?

This is a command line script running locally on the machine the files are on a network drive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `glob` rather than `opendir` and `readdir`?  They'll definitely be more space efficient.

Comment: No real reason I've just always used glob. Normally not with this many files. I didn't realize that readdir was more efficient.

Comment: `glob` returns an array with all the objects matching your pattern, whereas `opendir` returns a resource that can be iterated over using `readdir`.  If you can, give the `open/readdir` method a try and let me know how it works out.

Comment: `opendir(BASE)` with a loop grabbed all the files. So that worked.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear you've got a working solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> opendir(BASE) with a loop grabbed all the files. So that worked.